# Vector3.MoveTowards not working. It does not move or show any errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When using Vector3.MoveTowards, it won't do anything for either one, because one can't run which causes the other to not run.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class PlaneAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] runwayPoints;
    public Transform[] startTakeoffPoints;
    public Transform[] takeoffPoints;
    public NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;
    public bool takeoff = false;
    bool departing = false;
    bool moving = false;
    int selectedRunway;
    public IEnumerator Depart()
    {
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(runwayPoints[selectedRunway = Random.Range(0, runwayPoints.Length)].position);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        departing = true;
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Depart());
        }
        GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, new Vector3(transform.position.x, 1, transform.position.z));
        GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, navMeshAgent.destination);
        if (navMeshAgent.pathStatus == NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete && departing && navMeshAgent.remainingDistance == 0)
        {
            Takeoff();
        }
        if (moving && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, startTakeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position) <= 0.001f)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, takeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position, 3); // this one does not work it should be after the other one
            transform.LookAt(takeoffPoints[selectedRunway]);
            takeoff = false;
        }
    }
    public void Takeoff()
    {
        navMeshAgent.enabled = false;
        GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
        transform.LookAt(new Vector3(takeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position.x, 0, takeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position.z));
        MoveTakeoff();
        departing = false;
    }
    public void MoveTakeoff()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, startTakeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position, 2); // this one does not work
        moving = true;
        takeoff = false;
    }
}
```

There are no script errors, it just won't work.

The only errors that I don't think are related are:

"Invalid worldAABB. Object is too large or too far away from the origin."

"Invalid localAABB. Object transform is corrupt."

"Assertion failed on expression: 'IsFinite(d)'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr)"

"Assertion failed on expression: 'IsFinite(outDistanceForSort)'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr)"

"Assertion failed on expression: 'IsFinite(outDistanceAlongView)'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr)"

Comment: I see. But it moves a bit and it should run ```Vector3.MoveToward``` the entire way, right?

Comment: Nevermind, made a few variables and it worked great. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to better separate your state transition logic from your your state activity logic. You have code that should run when a state transition occurs in the same blocks as code that should run every frame a state is active.

One way you could handle this is by turning your states into coroutines:

```
public class PlaneAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] runwayPoints;
    public Transform[] startTakeoffPoints;
    public Transform[] takeoffPoints;
    public NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;
    public bool takeoff = false;
    bool departing = false;
    bool moving = false;
    int selectedRunway;

    LineRenderer lr;

    void Awake()
    { 
        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    IEnumerator Depart()
    {
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(runwayPoints[selectedRunway = Random.Range(0, 
                runwayPoints.Length)].position);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

        departing = true;
        while(departing)
        {           
            if (navMeshAgent.pathStatus == NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete 
                    && navMeshAgent.remainingDistance == 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(MoveTakeoff());
                yield break;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator MoveTakeOff()
    {
        departing = false;
        moving = true;

        navMeshAgent.enabled = false;
        GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
        transform.LookAt(new Vector3(takeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position.x, 0,
                takeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position.z));

        while (moving)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, 
                    startTakeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position) <= 0.001f)
            {                    
                StartCoroutine(TakeOff())
                yield return break;
            }

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
                    startTakeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position, 2);

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Takeoff()
    {
        moving = false;
        takeOff = true;

        transform.LookAt(takeoffPoints[selectedRunway]);

        while (takeOff)
        {
 
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, 
                    startTakeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position) <= 0.001f)
            {
                takeoff = false;
                yield break;
            }

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
                    takeoffPoints[selectedRunway].position, 3); 
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
            StartCoroutine(Depart());
        }

        lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(transform.position.x, 1, transform.position.z));
        lr.SetPosition(1, navMeshAgent.destination);

    }
}
```

Ideally, the states should be a single enumerator instead of several booleans, but this hopefully shows what I'm getting at.